# How do I apply the same change across dynamic widgets in python tkinter?

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter, widget

I have the following code to create dynamic checkboxes depending on how many rugby players from a certain position have been saved in a database:

```
#Dynamic Checkboxes
connectDB = sqlite3.connect("H:\\Python\\Uned_5\\Databases\\CDRR.db")
Cursor = connectDB.cursor()
Cursor.execute("SELECT firstName, surname FROM firstTeam WHERE position = 'Prop'")
nameResult = Cursor.fetchall()

for j in range(len(nameResult)):
    theText = nameResult[j]
    propCheckbutton = Checkbutton(framePropCheck, text = theText, bg = theBlue, fg = theWhite, font = ("calibri", 13), state = DISABLED)
    propCheckbutton.grid(row = 0, column = j)
```

This code is repeated to create dynamic checkboxes for every rugby position.

When you click a button associated with the player's position, it runs a function that disables all checkboxes apart from the position you click (think of it as a button that filters out player positions).  For example if I pressed the "prop" button, all other checkboxes will be disabled apart from the checkboxes containing players who play in the prop position.

This is the code relating to the button:

```
propButton = Button(framePosition, text = "Props", bg = theGray, fg = theWhite, font = ("calibri", 13), command = selectProps)
propButton.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
```

And this is the function that it leads to:

```
def selectProps():    
    try:
        propCheckbutton.config(state = NORMAL)
        hookerCheckbutton.config(state = DISABLED)
        lockCheckbutton.config(state = DISABLED)
        wingerCheckbutton.config(state = DISABLED)
        scrumCheckbutton.config(state = DISABLED)
        flyCheckbutton.config(state = DISABLED)
        centreCheckbutton.config(state = DISABLED)
        fullCheckbutton.config(state = DISABLED)
    except NameError:
        pass
```

When doing this with only 1 player from every position stored in the database everything works fine, but as soon as a second player is added to the same position as an existing player, the `.config` only applies to the latest dynamic checkbox.
For example if I had 2 players in the prop position, the first prop would still follow:

```
propCheckbutton = Checkbutton(framePropCheck, text = theText, bg = theBlue, fg = theWhite, font = ("calibri", 13), state = DISABLED)
```

whereas the second prop would follow:

```
propCheckbutton.config(state = NORMAL)
```

Is there a way I can make the `propCheckbutton.config(state = NORMAL)` apply to all dynamic checkboxes?

Here is the minimal, reproductible example that should work for others who want to see the issue:

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3
import sys
import os
pathname = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])

#This function only applies this propCheckbutton.config to the latest checkbox created 
def selectProps():    
    try:
        propCheckbutton.config(state = NORMAL)
        hookerCheckbutton.config(state = DISABLED)
    except NameError:
        pass

def selectHookers():
    try:
        propCheckbutton.config(state = DISABLED)
        hookerCheckbutton.config(state = NORMAL)
    except NameError:
        pass

#Creating a basic tkinter window
Window = Tk()
Window.geometry("700x700")

#Creating the table in database
connectDB = sqlite3.connect(pathname + "\\CDRR.db")
Cursor = connectDB.cursor()
Cursor.execute(
    """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS firstTeam(
        firstName text,
        surname text,
        position text
        )""")

#Inserting the data quickly and making sure the same data isn't inserted twice
normalText = str.maketrans("(),'[]",6*" ")
insertValues = ("INSERT INTO firstTeam (firstName, surname, position) VALUES (?, ?, ?)")
selectValues = ("SELECT firstName FROM firstTeam WHERE firstName = ?")
Cursor.execute(selectValues, [("Johnny")])
prop_1 = Cursor.fetchall()
prop_1 = str(prop_1)
prop_1.translate(normalText)
prop_1 = prop_1.strip()
if "Johnny" not in prop_1:
    Cursor.execute(insertValues, [("Johnny"), ("Silverhand"), ("Prop")])
else:
    pass

Cursor.execute(selectValues, [("Jackie")])
prop_2 = Cursor.fetchall()
prop_2 = str(prop_2)
prop_2.translate(normalText)
prop_2 = prop_2.strip()
if "Jackie" not in prop_2:
    Cursor.execute(insertValues, [("Jackie"), ("Welles"), ("Prop")])
else:
    pass

Cursor.execute(selectValues, [("Dexter")])
hooker_1 = Cursor.fetchall()
hooker_1 = str(hooker_1)
hooker_1.translate(normalText)
hooker_1 = hooker_1.strip()
if "Dexter" not in hooker_1:
    Cursor.execute(insertValues, [("Dexter"), ("DeShawn"), ("Hooker")])
else:
    pass

connectDB.commit()

#Buttons
propButton = Button(Window, text = "Props", command = selectProps)
propButton.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

hookerButton = Button(Window, text = "Hookers", command = selectHookers)
hookerButton.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

#Dynamic Checkboxes
Cursor.execute("SELECT firstName, surname FROM firstTeam WHERE position = 'Prop'")
nameResult = Cursor.fetchall()

for j in range(len(nameResult)):
    theText = nameResult[j]
    propCheckbutton = Checkbutton(Window, text = theText, state = DISABLED)
    propCheckbutton.grid(row = 1, column = j)

Cursor.execute("SELECT firstName, surname FROM firstTeam WHERE position = 'Hooker'")
nameResult = Cursor.fetchall()

for j in range(len(nameResult)):
    theRow = 0
    theText = nameResult[j]
    hookerCheckbutton = Checkbutton(Window, text = theText, state = DISABLED)
    hookerCheckbutton.grid(row = 2, column = j)

Window.mainloop()
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Could you please make a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it would be easier to work with.

Comment: I've just added that now, hopefully it recreates the problem for others so you can get a better understanding of the issue. @AST

Comment: By looking at your code, you have created the `Checkbutton`s using a loop, so the value held by `propCheckbutton` and the others would be the last assigned value at the end of the loop. You would need to store all the like checkbuttons in a list (append the instances in every iteration) and then in `selectProps` and similar functions, you will need to iterate through that and use the `config` method on them. Also, I don't think you need to involve database to reproduce it, strip it down further if possible.

Comment: The answer below demonstrates what you've said pretty well. You're right as well about not needing a database to reproduce the problem, it was just relevant to my project so I decided to include it. I could probably strip it down further so it would be more open to alternative solutions in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `dictionary` to store those `Checkbutton` widgets group by `position`, then you can easily enable/disable what you want:

```py
# enable the checkbuttons with given position
def select_position(position):
    for pos, players in buttons.items():
        for player in players:
            player.config(state=NORMAL if pos == position else DISABLED)

#Buttons
propButton = Button(Window, text="Props", command=lambda: select_position("Prop"))
propButton.grid(row=0, column=0)

hookerButton = Button(Window, text="Hookers", command=lambda: select_position("Hooker"))
hookerButton.grid(row=0, column=1)

buttons = {} # store the checkbuttons group by position

#Dynamic Checkboxes
for i, position in enumerate(["Prop", "Hooker"]):
    Cursor.execute("SELECT firstName, surname FROM firstTeam WHERE position = ?", (position,))
    nameResult = Cursor.fetchall()

    buttons[position] = []
    for j, theText in enumerate(nameResult):
        cb = Checkbutton(Window, text=theText, state=DISABLED)
        cb.grid(row=i+1, column=j)
        buttons[position].append(cb)
```

Comment: Thanks this was very easy to integrate into my project and makes perfect sense. It has also saved me a lot of lines from what I had written originally which is always good for efficiency.

Comment: One thing I have noticed is that if you select a player with the checkbox from one position, and then use the button to select another player postition; it works fine but the checkbox that was ticked is still selected. This is easily fixed though with ```player.deselect()``` in the ```select_position``` function to avoid any confusion from a user's point of view.